# Driven Harmonic Oscillation with Pre-Loaded Condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I hope I'm right here in that forum:

A simple harmonic driven damped single mass oscillator is described by the equation of motion:
$$ \ddot{x}=-\frac{d}{m}\dot{x}-\frac{k}{m}x+\frac{A}{m}sin(\omega t) $$

I try to calculate the force over time driving the mass point with the amplitude $\textit{A}$ and frequency $\omega$ in a pre-loaded spring condition. The amplitude is smaller than the deflection $\textit{x}$ needed to pre-load the spring. When I just add $F_{const}$ to the right term the calculated root point force the result is not as expected.
$$ \ddot{x}=-\frac{d}{m}\dot{x}-\frac{k}{m}x+\frac{A}{m}sin(\omega t)+\frac{F_{const}}{m} $$
After solving the equation with $F_{const}=2N$ in Matlab the root point force is oscillating around 3N. And the initial displacement is higher with pre-load. This is not expected.

The root point force is calculated with $F_{R}=x(t)k+F_{const}$.
Can anybody guide me how to set up the equation of motion?

without pre-load in euqation

[image: without pre-load]

with pre-load in equation

[image]

Comment: With a preload I assume that the force does not exist once the motion has started, so use the initial extension/compression of the spring as an initial condition?

Comment: @Farcher: I assume so as well. The constant force disappears for the pure motion. With the 1st derivative of the original equation of motion the constant force disappears. So, I cannot just add the constant force to the Matlab equation since this is the first derivative form. My second plot is wrong.
Let me check your approach ...